# Adding labels to a d3 horizontal bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm quite new to d3, I have a very simple bar chart that is 50px wide for every number that I pass it per row. I'm trying to add labels to go before the bar itself so that a viewer can make sense of what it represents.

Here's my code:

```
      var data2 = [4, 3, 1, 1];
      var fwSkills = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

      d3.select(".frameworks")
        .selectAll("div")
          .data(data2)
        .enter().append("div")
          .style("width", function(e) { return e * 50 + "px"; })
          .text(function(e) { return e; });
```

This doesn't add the labels at all, but everything I've tried so far doesn't work (or at least doesn't render the bar correctly). There's a bit of CSS to style the bar itself as well. I want to add the labels in the array *fwSkills* to be in front of their respective bars.

What can I do here? I feel that it's a simple JS fix. Thank you!

Comment: Assuming the `bit of CSS to style the bar` includes a background-color, your [code works fine for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/MmL2nmwYYMsDu1iLuWQK?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, made a clarification. There's the second array fwSkills whose values I want to add prior to the bars themselves. That array will hold the names of the bars whose values are represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append a div element for each data value. Then inside each of those div elements, you could append a div element for the label and a div element for the bar. For example...

```js
var data2 = [4, 3, 1, 1];
var fwSkills = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

var divs = d3.select(".frameworks")
    .selectAll("div")
        .data(data2)
    .enter()
        .append("div");

// add labels
divs.append("div")
    .classed("label", true)
    .style("width", "20px")
    .text(function (e,i ) { return fwSkills[i]; });
       
// add bars
divs.append("div")
    .classed("bar", true)
    .style("width", function(e) { return e * 50 + "px"; })
    .text(function(e) { return e; });
```

```css
.label {
    display: inline-block;
}

.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: steelBlue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="frameworks"></div>
```